# django template group results into different javascript objects

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have lots of entries with a `channel(int)`,`level(int)` and `entrytime(DateTimeField)`
passing the filtered results into the template, then I need to create different javascript objects for each channel with the objects name being the channel number and the array of values being level and entrytime with the entrytime being unix timestamp.

i.e.

```
var channel23 = [[1262905200000, 115],[1262818800000, 115],[1262732400000, 115],[1262646000000, 122],[1261954800000, 123]]

var channel11 = [[1262905200000, 60],[1262818800000, 60],[1262732400000, 60],[1262646000000, 55]];
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is confusing. Would you mind rewording the question, or adding a bit more context?

Comment: Sorry, I have a django model with channel,level and time, I want to view the data on a graph using the javascript lib "flot".With a line for each channel, to do this i need the data in javascript objects as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has to do this I got it working using the regroup in template, snippet below:

{% regroup results|dictsort:"channel" by channel as results_list %}